# How to append a variable in a text file after a certain word?

Tags: text-processing, sed

I want to append a variable in a text file after a word "begin".
`echo $variable` gives

```
rn=45
fg=12
cd=6
```

My text file looks like this

```
mixture
  Molefraction
  begin
END_OF_FILE
```

My desired output

```
mixture
  Molefraction
  begin
  rn=45
  fg=12
  cd=6
END_OF_FILE
```

I am using this `sed` command

```
sed -i "/begin/a $variable" file.txt
```

This is giving an error message like this

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 56: extra characters after command
```

Comment: (1) `$variable` is expanded *before* `sed` is executed. No figure out how the script looks after expansion. It will have line breaks, telling `sed` that this ends the current command (`a`) and starts a new command! That can't work. (2) Do you expect the inserted lines to be indented correctly, like in your example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `sed` and a shell that knows about "here-strings":

```
$ sed '/begin/r/dev/stdin' file <<<"$variable"
mixture
  Molefraction
  begin
rn=45
fg=12
cd=6
END_OF_FILE
```

This looks for the string `begin` in `file` and when this is matched, whatever is on standard input is inserted.  We pass the value of `$variable` on standard input via a here-string.

For other shells, the here-string is trivially replaced by `printf` over a pipe:

```sh
$ printf '%s\n' "$variable" | sed '/begin/r/dev/stdin' file
mixture
  Molefraction
  begin
rn=45
fg=12
cd=6
END_OF_FILE
```

To save this to a new file, use a redirection at the end.  If your `sed` supports in-place editing with `sed -i`, this could be used to modify the original file (testing this on a copy of the file would be advised; and running it several times would add the data to the file several times).

To get the correct indentation in e.g. `bash`:

```bash
$ ( set -f; IFS=$'\n'; printf '  %s\n' $variable ) | sed  '/begin/r/dev/stdin' file
mixture
  Molefraction
  begin
  rn=45
  fg=12
  cd=6
END_OF_FILE
```

Here, we rely on the shell's word splitting to format the value of the variable.  We use `set -f` to make sure that no filename globbing occurs, then we set `$IFS` to a newline, and let the shell split the value of the variable into newline-delimited words.  The `printf` is slightly modified to insert two spaces in front of each word.

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -v f="$variable" '/begin/{print; print f; next}1' input
```

This will look for a line containing `begin`, print it, then print the variable contents, then move to the next line. Defaulting to simply printing any other line.

Note: this will not indent the variable as is shown in your example.

---

With GNU awk you can edit your file in place using the `-i` option:

```
awk -iv f="$variable" '/begin/{print; print f; next}1' input
```

With all other versions of `awk` you will need to create a new file:

```
awk -v f="$variable" '/begin/{print; print f; next}1' input > newfile
```

You can then use `mv` to replace your old file with the new file if you desire

Comment: But this is not adding the variable the input file. It's just throwing everything in the command line.

Comment: @Mr.206: Yes you will have to redirect it to another file